# How to list all the jms headers attributes in apache camel?

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to read the jms header in apache-camel route. The following is the route in which I'm reading body & header.

```
String endPointTopic = "activemq:topic:geoLoc";
String endPointTopicOut = endPointTopic + "_outbox";    
from(endPointTopic)                 
    .log("Message from Topic is ${body} & header is ${header.Action}")
    .to(endPointTopicOut);
```

Basically the And from the logs I'm able to see the following, which means I'm able to read the body but not the id in header.

> Message from Topic is GeoLocationInfoDTO{id=2, geoLocationUUId='null',
>   geoLocationName='null', geoLocationDesc='null',
>   geoLocationPolygon='null', geoLocationCenterLatitude='null',
>   geoLocationCenterLongitude='null'} & header is

And the following is the code in which I'm publishing the message to activeMQ through jms template.

```
private MessageHeaders getMessageHeaders(HttpMethod action) {
    log.debug("DomainPublisher : getMessageHeaders");

    Map <String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    headerMap.put("Action", action);

    return new MessageHeaders(headerMap);
}

public void publish(BaseDTO dto, HttpMethod action) {
    log.debug("DomainPublisher : type is : {} : ", dto.getClass().getName());
    getJmsMessagingTemplate().convertAndSend(topicMap.get(dto.getClass().getName()), dto, getMessageHeaders(action));
}
```

**Note: I also tried to log the header id like ${header.id} instead of ${header.Action} but nothing is getting printed.**

*And I also wanted to know all the headers that are available to the jms message.*

Comment: If you post the logger out (.`to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")`) here, it will help us to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are you deploying the code to a karaf container ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can log exchange with all headers and properties as shown in this example:

```
.to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
```

http://camel.apache.org/log.html

More information about JMS headers can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

List of possible headers:

- JMSCorrelationID - The JMS correlation ID.
- JMSDeliveryMode - The JMS delivery mode.
- JMSDestination - The JMS destination.
- JMSExpiration - The JMS expiration.
- JMSMessageID - The JMS unique message ID.
- JMSPriority - The JMS priority (with 0 as the lowest priority and 9 as the highest).
- JMSRedelivered - Is the JMS message redelivered.
- JMSReplyTo - The JMS reply-to destination.
- JMSTimestamp - The JMS timestamp.
- JMSType - The JMS type.
- JMSXGroupID - The JMS group ID.

Comment: Thanks that helped me to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Claus Ibsen](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/245924?start=0&tstart=0) comment looks like JMS headers only allow certain types as headers and camel will drop invalid headers. And it looks like HttpMethod (type Enum) is been dropped by Camel. All I have to do in my code is convert the Enum as String while constructing the header.

```
headerMap.put("Action", action); 
          to
headerMap.put("Action", action.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The JMS headers can be viewed from the karaf client console by running the following command:

```
activemq:browse --amqurl tcp://localhost:61616 --msgsel JMSMessaageID='1' -Vheader TEST.FOO
```

Note: The above are all example values, change according to your config.